# 2 Coil Latching Relay

Tags: relay, latching-relay

I am using a 2 Coil Latching Relay and I was hoping that someone could confirm if my understanding of the relay I am using is correct. The part number I am using is a TQ2SA-24V (https://api.pim.na.industrial.panasonic.com/file_stream/main/fileversion/4514). From their datasheet, the manf states that the part is shipped out in the RESET position.

[image]

So, based off the datasheet, if pin 8 is common for the top side and pin 3 is common for the bottom side, I expect Pin 8 to be connected w/Pin 9 and Pin 3 to be connected w/Pin 2 when receiving the part for the first time, correct?

Now, let's say I want to switch it such that Pin 8 is now connected to Pin 7 and Pin 3 is connected to Pin 4. In order to do so, I have to put the relay in a SET state, ie. I need to apply 24V to Pin 1 and Ground to Pin 5. Is that a correct assumption?

If I were to want to put the relay back in a RESET state, ie. pin 8 is now connected back to 9 and pin 3 is now connected to pin 2, I would just need to apply 24V to Pin 10 and GND to Pin 6?

What would happen if I applied 24V to Pin 6 and GND to Pin 10? Would it switch only pin 8 to 7? Or is this not a used case?

Sorry for what might be a remedial question, but this is actually my first time working with latching relays and I think I've exhausted all attempts online to figure this out, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, based off the datasheet, if pin 8 is common for the top side and pin 3 is common for the bottom side, I expect Pin 8 to be connected w/Pin 9 and Pin 3 to be connected w/Pin 2 when receiving the part for the first time, correct?

Yes. Pin 9 and 2 are called NC (normally closed) contacts, 7 and 4 are called NO (normally open) contacts, and 3 and 8 are COM (common).

> Now, let's say I want to switch it such that Pin 8 is now connected to Pin 7 and Pin 3 is connected to Pin 4. In order to do so, I have to put the relay in a SET state, ie. I need to apply 24V to Pin 1 and Ground to Pin 5. Is that a correct assumption?

Yes. You should apply the rated coil voltage (24 V for your relay) across the SET (white) coil with shown polarity and for at least the commutation (operate or release) time which is specified in the datasheet (usually up to 10 ms).

> If I were to want to put the relay back in a RESET state, ie. pin 8 is now connected back to 9 and pin 3 is now connected to pin 2, I would just need to apply 24V to Pin 10 and GND to Pin 6?

Yes. Just like in the SET coil, you should apply the rated voltage across the RESET coil to put the contacts in reset (a.k.a. relaxed) state.

> What would happen if I applied 24V to Pin 6 and GND to Pin 10? Would it switch only pin 8 to 7? Or is this not a used case?

A polarised coil is not supposed to be driven with a reversed-polarity voltage. They have a diode connected in parallel internally, so once you apply the coil voltage in reverse polarity the diode will clamp the voltage which then may result in either the voltage source's protection or the diode's failure (destruction or short). This is clearly indicated on p.17:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for going thru and validating my assumption and calling out the last item on the datasheet that I missed.